# Firebase Functions is always trying to call us-central1 Functions wether it's initialized with a specific region or not

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

## The Problem

In my JavaScript Project I try to call a firebase function from a Client.
My current problem is that wether I set a region or not while initializing functions the called URL (from firebase function) always starts with the same region.

### My Code

functions.js (Firebase function - Server)

```
exports.recursiveDelete = functions.region('europe-west1')
  .runWith({
    timeoutSeconds: 540,
    memory: '2GB'
  })
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    // Doing smth.

  });
```

delete.js (Client)

```
const app = firebase.app();
const functions_delete = app.functions("europe-west1");

function deleteArtWork(path, pid) {
    
    var deleteFn = functions_delete.httpsCallable('recursiveDelete');
    deleteFn({ path: path, pid: pid }).then(function(result) {
            logMessage('Delete success: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
            window.location.href = "../";
        }).catch(function(err) {
            logMessage('Delete failed, see console,');
            console.warn(err);
        });

}
```

Firebase itself is correctly initialized because Firestore and Auth are having no trouble.

### The Output

```
[Error] Preflight response is not successful
[Error] Fetch API cannot load https://us-central1-projectart-jjl.cloudfunctions.net/recursiveDelete due to access control checks.
[Error] Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful (recursiveDelete, line 0)
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: logMessage
```

#### Why is Firebase function always trying to call the us-central1 function?

Did I do something wrong?

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding [HTTP and client-callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#http_and_client-callable_functions), "If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for Firebase Hosting, you must use us-central1."